# Display a String in a view returned by a Spring Boot Thymeleaf controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am struggling with my view, I need to display the return of my API function on my view:

> **Spring Controller Code**

```
@Controller
public class mainController {

  @RequestMapping(value = {"/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String index() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    DriveQuickstart drive = new DriveQuickstart("c:/temp/credentials.json");
    String res = drive.checkFile("cwg");

    return res;
```

`drive.checkFile` is an API function which returns a `String`.

I need to display it on my view `index.html`.
thank you very mutch.

Comment: use `@RestController`? or add `@ResponseBody` to you controller method?

Comment: @Keijack it's one or the other. Having `@RestController` already adds `@ResponseBody` to your methods. `* Types that carry this annotation are treated as controllers where
 * {@link RequestMapping @RequestMapping} methods assume
 * {@link ResponseBody @ResponseBody} semantics by default.`

Comment: Are you going to use this method with no ajax request? If so, then you will get blank page with string returned by the method.

Comment: yes, i got the blank page, and i have 0 ajax experience so far. could u give me some clue how it could works?

Comment: @Pijotrek Yes, you are right, so I use `or`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your method as below:

```
@RestController
public class mainController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String index() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    DriveQuickstart drive = new DriveQuickstart("c:/temp/credentials.json");
    String res = drive.checkFile("cwg");

    return res;
}
```

---

The modification i did is:
replaced `@Controller`  with `@RestController`  and
updated `@RequestMapping`

Comment: Hello, thx for your answer, i already did that, but it just display the string on a white page. my goal is to build a small interface where i can create/ display/ delete file.  So i need to display it on my html page

Comment: Hope you will be calling this REST service by AJAX call from your **html**, in your AJAX call you will get output of this method as response String. Use this string (response value) and display in your html page.

Comment: **Great !** One up vote will be appreciated :P Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        DriveQuickstart drive = new DriveQuickstart("c:/temp/credentials.json");
        model.addAttribute("drive", drive)
    return "/routeToTemplate";
    }
```

in thymeleaf

```
<div th:text="${drive}"></div>
```

Comment: hi thx for your answer, but in index.html he cant resolve ${drive} cant figure out why.

Comment: any suggestion ? my return might be wrong ? if  i need to display it on templates/index.html

Comment: Can you point to your code and index.html in a project or at least the directory layout, otherwise it's hard to tell what's not working for you.